# How do i update an array in mongo database collection

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, spring-data-mongodb

Hi I have a database named 'test' having collection name'test1' and in this collection i have an array named as  'passed' having one attribute 'name'. Now i want to add another default attribute to this array ( validation: "Not Validate"). Is it doable using update collection query using mongo?

Comment: Post your code.

Comment: You update an array of sub-documents using the `$[]` [all positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/index.html). With this you can _set_ all the sub-documents in the array with another attribute (like validation: "Not Validate").